# Mathematical operation of ABS() in objective function of PuLP

Tags: python-3.x, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to build a LP problem in PuLP and since I am new to python, wanted to know how to write the objective function with the operation of absolute values.

Till now I was using AMPL for my problem formulation and now want to convert the whole model to Python. Can anyone help me understand how to code

```
SUM(ABS(x)) in objective function of PulP
x is the decision variable which is output of the model and objective function of the model is SUM(ABS(x))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Can you share your code, what you want it to do, and in what way it isn't currently working. For more advice on writing good questions (likely to get good answers) please see [mcve]

Comment: `min sum(abs(x))` is easy. Standard formulations (see any book on linear programming) can be applied. `max sum(abs(x))` is more difficult: it requires binary variables.

Comment: Hi @kabdulla: I cannot share the code, as it contains my employer proprietary information. However, I am building a model, which optimizes the production plan, based on shortages seen. So if there are shortages in particular product then the inventory level will be -ve and for some product it will be positive. To optimize the inventory levels I need the objective function as min sum(abs(x)). I was using AMPL before and it was working fine, but I am not getting any good resource to understand the syntax for PuLP

Comment: Hi @ErwinKalvelagen: Thanks for the info. I got it. I used below link to solve the issue.

Comment: http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/absolute.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from pulp import *

N = 3
x_vars = LpVariable.dicts("x",range(N))
x_vars_abs = LpVariable.dicts("x_abs",range(N))
prob = LpProblem("min_sum_abs", LpMinimize)

# OBJECTIVE
prob += lpSum(x_vars_abs)

# ABS CONSTRAINTS
for i in range(N):
    prob += x_vars_abs[i] >= x_vars[i]
    prob += x_vars_abs[i] >= -x_vars[i]

# OTHER MODEL CONSTRAINTS
prob += lpSum(x_vars) >= 2.0
prob += x_vars[0] >= x_vars[1] + 1.0
prob += x_vars[1] <= x_vars[2] - 2.0

prob.solve()

print ("Status: " + str(LpStatus[prob.status]))
print ("Objective: " + str(value(prob.objective)))

for v in prob.variables():
    print (v.name + " = " + str(v.varValue))
```

Returns:

```
Status: Optimal
Objective: 2.6666667
x_0 = 0.66666667
x_1 = -0.33333333
x_2 = 1.6666667
x_abs_0 = 0.66666667
x_abs_1 = 0.33333333
x_abs_2 = 1.6666667
```

Comment: Thank you! I did the same thing and got the results desired. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great. For future reference the above would be an example of a [mcve]. - The least amount of code, in a working form, to allow someone else to very easily show you the missing step(s).